# Single class dependency

Tags: java, class, dependencies

I have created two separate Java projects/packages that use the same class. If I change the code of the class in one of the projects I should also change the code in the other project. I want to keep the projects/packages as separated as possible, that is I don't want one to depend on the other in any way. How should I extract this class so the change is visible in both of the projects. Is a package with only one class a good approach?

Comment: It is not a good approach, but it's what you have. So yes, define a new jar to handle the common classes for your projects.

Comment: You should use a dependency management tool like Maven. So whenever you compile your class and if the class on which it is dependent has been modified, it will pick the latest class to compile yours.

Comment: I am using Maven but how is that going to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good approach, but it's what you have. So yes, define a new jar to handle the common classes for your projects, even if is a single common class. Probably later in your projects you will encounter more classes to use or split this single class into more classes.

Comment: Ok, I will try it and if no other solutions exist I'll mark your answer